Weak or low air vent flow
My master bedroom and my master bathroom of our double wide trailer have the worst or lowest air flowing into the rooms which causes both rooms to either not get warm/cool enough in the winter/summer months unless I turn the thermostat up and then rest of the house be either too hot (winter) or either to cool (summer)
I even thought about getting a vent with built in fans and thermostat on it.
Any suggestions to get efficient and even air flowing throughout the home?
(Oh by the way I am currently having to use a an electric heater which is hiring my pocket in the winter months so I gotta do something different this winter)
Thanks for your input and suggestions

Do you have vent that come up through the floor or overhead through the ceiling?  How old is the home?

For forced-air heating, there are vent (register) booster fans, such as these from Amazon or Lowes.
That said, it would be good to look for obstructions in the ducts (e.g., crushed duct or rodent nest), and insulation lost or water-logged around the ducts. If it's difficult to look from outside, there are endoscopes (tiny cameras on a probe cable) that can be rented or purchased, such as these from Amazon.
Links to products are for purpose of illustration only.
